# How to get more than one report from one ROBOT test execution?

Tags: report, robotframework

my management would like to have a simple switch to trigger the generated ROBOT test reports, to get from one test execution two reports: one comprehensive detailed report (xml, html) and one management-level report with general info and without many technical details.

Is there a standard ROBOT mechanism to generate two different reports at once?

How would you do?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robot has the built-in ability to generate four types of outputs:

- [log.html](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#log-file) is a detailed low level log of test execution, showing the details of every suite, test case, and keyword (parameters, results, duration)
- [report.html](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#report-file) is a more high level overview of test execution
- [output.xml](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#output-file) is a detailed log of all of the data used to generate the other reports
- [xUnit](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#xunit) is an XUnit-compatible file that can be processed by many xUnit-compatibile tools

The log.html, report.html, and output.xml files are all generated by default. Generating the xUnit output requires the use of a command line option.

If none of those meet your need, there is an [API](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.4/autodoc/robot.result.html) for reading and processing the output.xml file which you can use to generate a custom report. The format of the output.xml file is very simple and easy to parse, so you can also use just about any xml parsing tool you want to parse the results and generate your own report.

All of this information is available in the [robot frame user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html), in a section titled [Created outputs](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#created-outputs).